# Data and tooltip not working for graph using highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to get a basic column chart working where I will trend for maphours(y-axis), reducehours(y-axis) for a particular job(tooltip) on a particular day(x-axis).

I am populating the data array with y-axis values and jobname value which I want to show in the tooltip. The x-axis value is a datestamp(a daily value i.e one date throughout the x-axis).

Problem - The graph container is getting initiated but it is not picking up the y-axis values and tooltip.

The code where i am populating the arrays -

```
            var obj = data;
            var jobSummaryMappersPT = [];
            var jobSummaryReducersPT = [];
            var jobSummaryMappersDB = [];
            var jobSummaryReducersDB = [];
            var datestamp = [];

            for(i=0;i<obj.length-1;i++){

                  if(obj[i].grid=='PT'){
                          jobSummaryMappersPT.push({mappers: obj[i].maphours, jobname: obj[i].jobname}); // Filling of Array after Ajax Call
                          jobSummaryReducersPT.push({reducers: obj[i].reducehours, jobname: obj[i].jobname}); //Filling of Array
                          datestamp.push(obj[i].date.replace('T00:00:00.000Z', ' '));
                  }else{ 
                          jobSummaryMappersDB.push({mappers: obj[i].maphours, jobname: obj[i].jobname}); // Filling of Array after Ajax Call
                          jobSummaryReducersDB.push({reducers: obj[i].reducehours, jobname: obj[i].jobname}); //Filling of Array

                  }
            }
            job_summary_chart(jobSummaryMappersPT, jobSummaryReducersPT, jobSummaryMappersDB, jobSummaryReducersDB, datestamp);
```

The function where I am initiating my Highcharts -

```
 function job_summary_chart(jobSummaryMappersPT, jobSummaryReducersPT, jobSummaryMappersDB, jobSummaryReducersDB, datestamp){
    $(function () {
    $('#job_summary_pt').highcharts({
     // Other Highchart Properties
     chart: {
                                              type: 'column'
                                              },
                                              title: {
                            text: 'Job Summary',
                                  x: -20 //center
                            },
                            subtitle: {
                                text: 'Source: DFTBA',
                                x: -20
                            },
                            xAxis: {
                              categories: datestamp,
                              labels: {
                                      rotation: -45,
                                      y: 30,
                                      align: 'center',
                                      step: 4
                              }
                            },
                            yAxis: {
                                title: {
                                      text: 'GbHrs'
                                },
                                plotLines: [{
                                      value: 0,
                                      width: 1,
                                      color: '#808080'
                                }]   
                            }, 
                            tooltip: {
                                valueSuffix: ' GbHrs',
                                formatter: function() { return ' ' +
                                    'Jobname: ' + this.point.jobname + '<br />'

                               } 
                            },
                            legend: {
                                layout: 'vertical',
                                align: 'right',
                                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                                borderWidth: 0
                              },
                            series: [{
                               data: jobSummaryMappersPT
                            },{
                               data: jobSummaryReducersPT
                            }]
                        });
```

i did a console.log on jobSummaryMappersPT and the values are as follows:

```
 [Object { mappers=97, jobname="abcd.pig"}, 
     Object { mappers=33, jobname="abcd.pig"},          
     Object { mappers=31, jobname="abcd.pig"}, 
     Object { mappers=15, jobname="abcd.pig"}, 
     Object { mappers=15, jobname="abcd.pig"}, 
     Object { mappers=12, jobname="abcd.pig"}]
```

I think the issue is the "=" sign after mappers and jobname. In the data property, it accepts colons = ":" and thats why the graph is not picking up values?

How do i fix this to get the graph working? and get the tooltip to show the jobname?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your problem is not only with the tooltip, the chart could not even render with your data. You set `mappers` and `reducers` as the property names of Y value, but **how can highcharts know those properties are where it should pick Y values**?

Changing properties `mappers` and `reducers` to `y` should make it work:

```
jobSummaryMappersPT.push({y: obj[i].maphours, jobname: obj[i].jobname}); // Filling of Array after Ajax Call
jobSummaryReducersPT.push({y: obj[i].reducehours, jobname: obj[i].jobname}); //Filling of Array
```

The code for tooltip looks fine to me.